# How to set up environment variables in yaml arg-file with gcloud cli for Firebase Test Lab

Tags: firebase, gcloud, firebase-test-lab

This gcloud command for starting an instrumentation test on Firebase Test Lab works fine:

```
 gcloud firebase test android run \ 
 --type instrumentation \ 
 --app app/build/outputs/apk/demo/debug/app-demo-debug.apk 
 --test app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/demo/debug/app-demo-debug-androidTest.apk \
 --device model=Nexus6,version=21,locale=en,orientation=portrait
 --environment-variables cucumberOptions="--tags '@demo and @e2e'"
```

However, when I try to extract the arguments into an arg-spec yaml file, I have problems defining the environment variables:

```
gcloud firebase test android run firebase/testlab/tests.yaml:demo-cucumber-E2E-test
```

firebase/testlab/tests.yaml:

```
demo-cucumber-E2E-test:
   type: instrumentation
   app: app/build/outputs/apk/demo/debug/app-demo-debug.apk
   test: app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/demo/debug/app-demo-debug-androidTest.apk
   device: [{model: Nexus6, version: 21, locale: en, orientation: portrait}]
   environment-variables: [{cucumberOptions="--tags '@demo and @e2e'"}]
```

I get the following Error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.firebase.test.android.run) Invalid value for
>   [environment-variables]: Malformed key-value pairs.

How can I define the environment variables in the arg-spec yaml file in a correct way?

Comment: Try indenting everything under the `demo-cucumber-E2E-test` key so that e.g. `type` becomes a child key rather than sibling.

Comment: Should it not be `{cucumberOptions: "...."}`?

Comment: A workaround would be to specify both your yaml file and your environment variables in the gcloud command.

`gcloud firebase test android run [arg.yaml] --environment-variables var1=value`

It might be that the environment variables are being set since they are written in the yaml file instead of being declared in the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why the encoding into an array doesn't work, but you can make it work by formating the yaml file the following way:

```
demo-cucumber-E2E-test:
  type: instrumentation
  app: app/build/outputs/apk/demo/debug/app-demo-debug.apk
  test: app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/demo/debug/app-demo-debug-androidTest.apk
  device:
    - model: Nexus6
      version: 21
      locale: 'en'
      orientation: portrait
  environment-variables:
    cucumberOptions: "--tags '@demo and @e2e'"
```

**EDIT**

I figured out why your initial example did not work. It needed 2 changes:

- Replace `=` with `:`
- Remove the array `[]` for `environment-variables`

```
demo-cucumber-E2E-test:
   type: instrumentation
   app: app/build/outputs/apk/demo/debug/app-demo-debug.apk
   test: app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/demo/debug/app-demo-debug-androidTest.apk
   device: [{model: Nexus6, version: 21, locale: en, orientation: portrait}]
   environment-variables: {cucumberOptions: "--tags '@demo and @e2e'"}
```

Comment: Right, the original formatting didn't work because

`cucumberOptions="--tags '@demo and @e2e'"`

needs to be changed to:

`cucumberOptions: "--tags '@demo and @e2e'"`

Comment: Hmm I tried that before and it didn't work for me. The line looks like this now but still throws the same error: `environment-variables: [{cucumberOptions: "--tags '@demo and @e2e'"}]`. Only reformatting worked for me here.

Comment: Added a 2nd example that looks more closer to your existing question, highlighting the things that were wrong.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Maik. 
`device:` is an list of dictionaries (you can specify multiple devices, each with certain properties), while `environment-variables:` is just a straight dictionary.